# failed to mount local volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute docker-compose for this configuration:

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        hostname: db.magento2.docker
        image: mariadb:latest
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
            MYSQL_USER: 'db-user'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database_name'
        volumes:
            - 'mymagento-magento-sync:/app:delegated'
            - 'mymagento-magento-db:/var/lib/mysql'
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        networks:
            magento:
                aliases:
                    - db.magento2.docker
volumes:
    mymagento-magento-sync:
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            device: '${PWD}/mymagento-magento-sync'
            o: bind
    mymagento-magento-db: {}
networks:
    magento:
        driver: bridge
    magento-build:
        driver: bridge
```

When I run docker-compose, I get following message:

Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/folder_mymagento-magento-sync/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount mymagento-magento-sync:/var/lib/docker/volumes/folder_mymagento-magento-sync/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

I'm relatively new to docker, so I'd appreciate any hint how can I resolve this.

Best,
Bojan

Comment: Where is located your volume source ? You should give absolutes paths for volumes `/path/to/ mymagento-magento-sync:/app` or an explicit relative path with `./`

Comment: I'd usually expect a directory named `/app` to contain your main application code, and so to be included in your underlying Docker image.  If you delete the `mymagneto-magneto-sync` volume declaration and mount, do things work?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, if I remove the declararation, everithing starts normaly. I'll create app directory to see if it's starting.

Answer (score 4):

1. step 1:
   remove and clean your env

   > docker-compose -f docker.yml down -v
2. step 2:
   reinstall docker-compose

   > pip install docker-compose
3. restart your app

   > docker-compose -f docker.yml up -d

Comment: This also means that Python and pip must be installed, which is not intuitive

Answer (score 0):

```bash
docker run -it -d --mount source=<your_website>,target=/var/www/html -d -p 12:22 -d -p 187:80  -d -p 744:443  --restart always --name <container_name_website> <image_name>

mkdir -p /home/your/file/path

docker volume create --name your_website  --opt type=none --opt device=/home/your/file/path --opt o=bind
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your volume folder is not found by docker. So you can restore in recycle bin or delete your volume before.

Check your volume, if your volume is same in your docker-compose.yml, you can delete it.
Example :

```
docker volume rm mymagento-magento-sync
```